# Order of GCC optimization flags

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization

I would like to define a set of optimization sequences to an input C program in order to study the impact of my applied sequences to code performance.

example:

```
 gcc -fauto-inc-dec -fbranch-count-reg -fcombine-stack-adjustments ... test.c -o out.o
```

Does the order of these options affect the effectiveness of the produced code?

As well, applying an optimization option twice does have an impact?

Is there a better way to test thousands of optimization sequences? Like in -02 (that includes around 20 options), I would like to define my own flags

Answer (score 7):

- *Does the order of these options affect the effectiveness of the produced code?*

  - **No**, the order of these options passed as command line arguments to the compiler does not affect the effectiveness of the produced code.
- *Is there a better way to test thousands of optimization sequences?*

  - Since we don't have a optimization sequence w.r.t the optimization flags being passed to the compiler, we don't have a way to test. But, as you are aware, we have optimization levels which you can experiment with.
- Higher optimization levels perform more global transformations on the program and apply more expensive analysis algorithms in order to generate faster and more compact code. The price in compilation time, and the resulting improvement in execution time, both depend on the particular application and the hardware environment. You should experiment to find the best level for your application.
  Please refer to [Optimization Levels for GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Optimization-Levels.html)
- *I would like to define my own flags*
- Currently, gcc supports many flags which you can refer in [Optimize Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). If you would like to define a flag, then the compiler needs to understand that and you might need to modify compiler code for gcc so that it can understand a new flag. Please refer to code on github, [opts.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/7aea4e7cdcd40d7bd47c64e76325a62191887d1b/gcc/opts.c), opts.c deals with optimization flags and levels.
- *As well, applying an optimization option twice does have an impact?*

  - No, applying same optimization option twice will not have impact. For example: Executing `gcc -fauto-inc-dec -fauto-inc-dec test.c` would have the same impact as Executing `gcc -fauto-inc-dec test.c`.

(*Adding from comments regarding additional optimization passes* - You can write a gcc optimization plugin to make additional passes. Please refer to this article: [An introduction to creating GCC plugins](https://lwn.net/Articles/457543/). The article helps to create plugin to do additional optimization pass, transforming code, or analyzing information.)

Comment: you said NO. However, in scientific paper I found this affirmation: "In optimizing compilers, it is standard practice to apply
the same set of optimizations phases in a fixed order on
each method of a program. However, several researchers, have shown that the best ordering of optimizations
varies within a program, i.e., it is function-specific. Thus,
we would like a technique that selects the best ordering of
optimizations for individual portions of the program, rather
than applying the same fixed set of optimizations for the
whole program."

https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~cavazos/oopsla-2012.pdf

Comment: @staticx: Yes, you are correct that the ordering of optimization passes matters.  However, the order in which command line arguments are given do not affect the optimization pass ordering in gcc.

Comment: @janneb I am not so familiar with gcc and optimization phases ordering problem. Ok, let's say I have a given C program and a list of optimization sequences. How can I make passes affecting code transformation ?

Comment: @staticx: The paper you shared is internally referring to MilePost GCC which is a machine learning based compiler. So, according to [MILEPOST GCC: machine learning based research compiler](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/ckiw/postscript/milepost-gcc.pdf), a new flag (-fici) is passed to GCC and when GCC detects these options, it loads a ICI_PLUGIN and the machine learning model predicts the best GCC optimization to apply for that program.

Comment: Ok. Let's say that 'BY DEFAULT' changing gcc optimization options order through command line is not possible.

However, to investigate more on passes ordering problem, I think it is possible to edit the source code (gcc/passes.c) or  write a 
plugin to handle that.

Am I right ?

Comment: Thanks for enriching my knowledge today. Yes, you can write a gcc optimization plugin to make additional passes. Please refer to this article: [An introduction to creating GCC plugins](https://lwn.net/Articles/457543/). The article helps to create plugin to do additional optimization pass, transforming code, or analyzing information. I guess you were looking for the same. Hope this helps. If this was what you were looking for, then I shall add the details in the answer and if you wish, you may accept the answer. Thanks again. :)

Comment: The above answer is correct. BTW,you might use [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to enhance GCC. And the optimization flags are setting parameters which are later used by GCC pass manager to order the optimizations (sometimes in a dynamic way). Details might be specific to a particular version of GCC, and `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org` (if you are just using optimizations) or `gcc@gcc.gnu.org` (if you are creating your plugin or MELT extension) are the best place to ask

Comment: A little late to the party but I think what you're referring to is an open problem called the "Phase Ordering Problem". A lot of work has been done on this specifically with the LLVM Compiler toolchain